# Does Koenig's lookup apply here?

Tags: c++

Is the following snippet correct C++ code?

```
#include <sstream>
class Foo;
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Foo x);  // (A)

namespace test {
  class Message {
  public:
    std::ostringstream str;
  };

  template<typename T>
  Message& operator<<(Message& m, T& t)
  {
    using ::operator<<;
    m.str << t;
    return m;
  }
}

namespace detail {
  class Class {
  public:
    int i;
    Class() : i(5) {}
  };
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, detail::Class& myClass) { // (B)
  return str << myClass.i;
}

int main() {
  test::Message m;
  detail::Class c;
  m << c;
}
```

According to http://goo.gl/NkPNau GCC compiles this fine, while Clang doesn't find the `operator<<` (B).

---

In case you are wondering: This is from a code that uses GTest with a custom `operator<<` for `std::set` to print nice assertion messages. We couldn't figure out a way to make it work with clang other than putting the `operator<<` (B) in std namespace (yeah I know...).

Comment: For future reference, when a compiler gives you an error, post the exact error (even if you are summarizing it right).

Comment: If it's valid, I don't see how it could be because of ADL (Koenig lookup): the expression doesn't have any type for which the global namespace is an associated namespace. I'm surprised GCC and Intel accept this, but I can't say they're wrong in doing so without understanding why they're doing so.

Comment: I believe Clang is correct, the code is invalid. Under two-phase lookup, `operator<<` is first looked up at the point of template definition; there, only (A) is visible, but is not viable. Then `operator<<` is looked up again at the point of instantiation - but only ADL is performed, not ordinary lookup. So (B) is not found, since global namespace is not associated with either argument.

Comment: To add to my earlier comment, GCC is doing so because GCC has [a known bug in how it resolves operators](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/PR51577). If there was still any question before of which compiler was right, there shouldn't be now.

Comment: Fiktik: Why do you have `using ::operator<<;`? Operators should be found by ADL, no need to provide a using declaration.

Comment: Fiktik: Instead of creating an artificial piece of code, you should ask about the specific problems. It is unclear whether you are forced into using `operator<<`, or what the exact types are. You mention `std::set`, but you don't mention what is contained in the set, or if you are using the default comparator or something else, or if you can wrap the test on something else...

Comment: @David the using declaration is there because of the first phase of the 2-phase lookup as Igor points out. Without it GCC rejects the code. Additionally, this is not my code, but an extract from GTest source. I asked the question because I wanted to understand if this code is valid or not and why - turns out it isn't. Now I can solve the original problem myself ... and if not I will ask a followup question. The note at the end is there to only satisfy people's curiosity.

Comment: @Fiktik: I am not seeing the real code so this might be a bit off, but in the code you present, that using declaration does nothing. The only thing in the global namespace is the `operator<<` that applies to `Foo`, and `Foo` already lives in that namespace, so ADL will find it without it.  Using declarations bring *only those identifiers that are visible at the point where the using declaration is encountered*, which in this case includes only the `Foo` overload. That using declaration (according to the standard) is useless --even if it modifies the buggy gcc behavior

Comment: @Fiktik: You still have not mentioned what the type inside the set is...

Comment: @David You are right, it has nothing to do with how name lookup works in standard C++, that was a bad formulation on my part. It just lets GCC accept the code. The type inside the set in my scenario was a plain integer. In the end I just replaced `operator<<` with a `ToString` function so that I stream a `std::string` instead like you suggested in a comment below. The using code is still reasonably nice.

Comment: After thinking about it a bit more, I am going to stop calling that gcc behavior *buggy* and leave it as *unhelpful*. The standard places the burden on the developer, not the compiler, to ensure that lookup for all instantiations of the template (and an additional one at the end of the translation unit) yields exactly the same symbols. Your program has undefined behavior and the compilers are doing whatever they please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang is correct here.  Let's call g++'s behavior a language extension.

Argument-dependent lookup (aka Koenig lookup) does apply, since `m.str << t` is interpreted using the best overload matching either `m.str.operator<<(t)` or `operator<<(m.str, t)`, and the second case is an *unqualified-id* as the function name.  But:

14.6.4.2:

> For a function call that depends on a template parameter, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1) or qualified name lookup (3.4.3), only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.
>
> If the function name is an *unqualified-id* and the call would be ill-formed or would find a better match had the lookup within the associated namespaces considered all the function declarations with external linkage introduced in those namespaces in all translation units, not just considering those declarations found in the template definition and template instantiation contexts, then the program has undefined behavior.

At the template definition context, (B) is not visible.  (B) is visible at the template instantiation context, but the global namespace is not an associated namespace of either `std::ostringstream` or `detail::Class`.

Comment: What will be a good standards compliant solution to accomplish what the OP wants to do?

Comment: I would put (B) inside `namespace detail`.  If you want it visible in the global namespace for some reason, `using detail::operator<<;`

Comment: @aschepler But unless I'm misreading the question, the OP's `operator<<` has a LHS and a RHS that are both part of the `std` namespace, and adding operators there for standard types is not usually a good idea.

Comment: @hvd: What `operator<<` has lhs and rhs in the `std` namespace? Clearly not the one with the `// B` comment, which is the one that needs to be moved...

Comment: @RSahu: The good standard compliant solution is using ADL for what it was designed and how it was designed. Operators shall be in the namespace of one of the two arguments.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Based on the comment following the code, in the real code, `detail::Class` is actually some instantiation of `std::set`.

Comment: @hvd: I missed that. Then the answer it not to use an operator. Either you define them where they should live, or you avoid them completely. I don't know what GTest does, if it requires the use of `operator<<` you have an interesting problem that requires more creative solutions, but unless the problem is correctly stated, it is not worth the time. BTW, if the set is of a user-defined type, then ADL will look inside that, so that is a fine place to provide the operator...